# Can I found $U$, $W$, and $X$ subspace in $V$ which satisfies $(U\cap X)+(W \cap X)\subset(U+W)\cap X.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can I found $U$, $W$, and $X$ subspace in $V$ which satisfies $$(U\cap X)+(W \cap X)\subset(U+W)\cap X.$$ I wonder what subspaces are satisfy this. Anyone can help me? Thx..

Comment: What do you denoe by $\subset$? A proper subset, I suppose.

Comment: These two subspaces always coincide.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in(U\cap X)+(W \cap X)$ so $a=u+v$ such that $u\in (U\cap X)$ and $v\in(W\cap X)$. Therefore because $X$ is a subspace $a\in X$ ($u,v \in X$) and $a\in U+W$ ($u\in U$ and $v\in V$).
So  $(U\cap X)+(W \cap X)\subset(U+W)\cap X$ for all $U,W,X$ subspaces.Q.E.D

Comment: what about the converse? is it true?

Comment: No, take in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , $U={x axis}, W={y axis}, X=\{ (x,x)|x\in \mathbb{R} \}$.